# Android CameraUpdateFactory is not initialized

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to develop android app with google maps, but I have error -

> NullPointerException: CameraUpdateFactory is not initialized

```
    GoogleMap mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);


    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();


    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 0, this);       

    double lat = Double.parseDouble("xx.xxxxxx");
    double log = Double.parseDouble("yy.yyyyyy");
    LatLng currentPosition = new LatLng(lat, log);

    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentPosition,16));
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(currentPosition)
            .snippet("Lat:" + lat + "Lng:" + log));
```

Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need implement

> OnMapReadyCallback

and then override

> onMapReady

This is to make sure that your map has been properly set and ready for any camera updates.

```
public class YourMapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback { 
...
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
mMap = googleMap;
mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentPosition,16));

    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(currentPosition)
            .snippet("Lat:" + lat + "Lng:" + log));
}

    ...
    }
```